# lit-element.js not found after polymer build

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I am currently encountering a problem which is probably simple, but I don't manage to nail it.

I have a polymer application using the latest version of lit-element (2.0.1).

Unfortunately after running the `npm run build:static` (behind it is `polymer build`) and serve it using: `npm run serve:static`  (behind it is executing: `polymer serve --port 5000 build/es5-bundled`).

The lit-element.js is not available.

If I list the files in the project node_module I have:

```
pxke@station:ls -1 node_modules/lit-element/
CHANGELOG.md
lib
LICENSE
lit-element.d.ts
lit-element.d.ts.map
lit-element.js
lit-element.js.map
package.json
README.md
src
```

The lit-element.js seems to be there, after the build if I look in the node_module of the build it is not copied.

```
g@station: ls -1 build/es5-bundled/node_modules/lit-element/
CHANGELOG.md
lib
LICENSE
lit-element.d.ts
lit-element.d.ts.map
lit-element.js.map
package.json
README.md
src
```

Do you know why this would happen? 
Thank you in advance. 
Have a great day!

Here are some extra information:
Dependency section of package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@material/base": ">=0.3.6",
"@material/mwc-base": ">=0.3.6",
"@material/mwc-button": ">=0.4.0",
"@material/mwc-icon": ">=0.3.6",
"@material/mwc-ripple": ">=0.3.6",
"@material/ripple": ">=0.3.6",
"@polymer/app-layout": ">=3.0.0",
"@polymer/paper-button": ">=3.0.1",
"@polymer/polymer": ">=3.1.0",
"@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": ">=2.2.4",
"browser-sync": "2.26.3",
"lit-element": ">=2.0.1",
"lit-html": ">=1.0.0",
"npm": "^6.9.0",
"pwa-helpers": "^0.9.0",
"redux": ">=4.0.0",
"redux-thunk": ">=2.3.0",
"reselect": "^4.0.0",
"sinon": "^4.5.0"
},
```

polymer.json

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/components/test-app.js",
  "sources": [
    "images/**/*"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/**",
    "node_modules/lit-element/**",
    "node_modules/lit-html/**",
    "node_modules/@material/mwc-button/**",
    "node_modules/@material/mwc-base/**",
    "node_modules/@material/base/**",
    "node_modules/@material/mwc-ripple/**",
    "node_modules/@material/ripple/**",
    "node_modules/@material/mwc-icon/**",
    "push-manifest.json"
  ],
  "builds": [
    {
      "name": "esm-bundled",
      "browserCapabilities": [
        "es2015",
        "modules"
      ],
      "js": {
        "minify": true
      },
      "css": {
        "minify": true
      },
      "html": {
        "minify": true
      },
      "bundle": true,
      "addServiceWorker": true
    },
    {
      "name": "es6-bundled",
      "browserCapabilities": [
        "es2015"
      ],
      "js": {
        "compile": "es2015",
        "minify": true,
        "transformModulesToAmd": true
      },
      "css": {
        "minify": true
      },
      "html": {
        "minify": true
      },
      "bundle": true,
      "addServiceWorker": true
    },
    {
      "name": "es5-bundled",
      "js": {
        "compile": "es5",
        "minify": true,
        "transformModulesToAmd": true
      },
      "css": {
        "minify": true
      },
      "html": {
        "minify": true
      },
      "bundle": true,
      "addServiceWorker": true
    }
  ],
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "npm": true
}
```

Comment: Why do you have all those node_modules extra dependencies? lit-element.js should be copied to the build folder if it's actually imported somewhere. Sounds like it's being bundled, but something else is still directly referencing it.

Comment: @JustinFagnani Thank you, for feedback. You are right,  I will not be able to explain it completely, it happens only when I Import the mwc-button definition into my HTML page.

As asked here:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/tree/master/packages/button

I have moved everything to component and it works like a charm. 

Thanks again for pointing it out. 

I was trying to fix things by adding all the libraries, and checking which 404 were remaining.

Have a lovely day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when you import lit-element, `Polymer build` may bundle the lit-element codes into built codes. You may not see at the path. But if you want to force to add the path then you may define in `polymer.json` file under `fragments`.  example:

polymer.json:

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/components/test-app.js",
  "sources": [
    "images/**/*"
  ],
  "fragments": [
     "node_modules/lit-element/**/*",
  ],
  "sources": [
    "images/**/*"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
  ...
```